# Откуда появились линии на скругленных углах картинки?

Tags: html, css

Я немного не запутан, и не хочу идти спать, пока не сделаю эту вещь.
Никак не могу понять, в чем тут косяк:

(Пробегитесь по коду, **внизу вопрос**)

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #2233aa, #2244ff 90%); <---- Change this*/ 
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
}
.banner:hover::before {
  opacity: .75;
}
.banner::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity .15s;
}
.banner .box {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.banner .box .image {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 320px;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/SRs4FQS/image.png);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.banner .box .image .description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.banner .box .image .description .title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
.banner .box .image .description .title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.banner .box .image .description .tag {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eaf;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="image">
      <div class="description">
        <h1 class="title"> <a href="#">lorem ipsum sit amet</a></h1>
        <div class="tag">html</div>
        <div class="tag">css</div>
        <div class="tag">js</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Может, тут есть проблемы, просто Я сел и на скорую руку слепил такой баннер.
Ничего необычно, но, раскомментируйте, пожалуйста, ту строчку кода, в `body`. когда поменятся цвет, наблюдайте:

- Появился градиент, все хорошо

Теперь постарайтесь приглядеться на **скругленные углы** этого `баннера` и обратите внимание на *очень тонкие белые линии*, почти на каждом углу.

### [image: Вглядитесь в верхний и нижний углы]

Я уже пробовал менять `border-radius` у все элементов и не выходило, помогите мне, пожалуйста разобрать ошибку. 
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Выглядит как баг браузеров

Answer (score 2):

Этот косячёк очень известный и лечится как правило скрытием всего того что вылазиет за пределы родителя ..к примеру вот так :

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #2233aa, #2244ff 90%); <---- Change this*/
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
}

.banner:hover::before {
  opacity: .75;
}

.banner::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity .15s;
}

.banner .box {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner .box .image {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 320px;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/SRs4FQS/image.png);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.banner .box .image .description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.banner .box .image .description .title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.banner .box .image .description .title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner .box .image .description .tag {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eaf;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="image">
      <div class="description">
        <h1 class="title"> <a href="#">lorem ipsum sit amet</a></h1>
        <div class="tag">html</div>
        <div class="tag">css</div>
        <div class="tag">js</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы отдельно указать, что именно исправили, чтобы не пересканировать заново всю простыню

Comment: @SergeyNudnov я в родительский блок в котором находится блок с background сделал overflow:hidden; там в css это видно и больше ни чего ни делал

Comment: Прекрасно! Будем знать. Спасибо

Comment: @SergeyNudnov если ответ помог отметье решением

Comment: Я его отметил заслуженным +. А насчет решения - это к автору вопроса. :)

Comment: @SergeyNudnov а да да ..точно точно ..сорри

Comment: Проблема слегка замаскировалась, но никуда не делась — угол всё ещё содержит светлые точки https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOhX1.png

Comment: @andreymal это уже не то что было ...

Comment: Хорошее решение, воспользовался вашим кодом и смотрится вполне) Благодарю!

Comment: @АндрейДобрин т.е помогло ?

Comment: К сожалению, не совсем. Если поменять цвет родительского элемента на более светлый, можно заметить снова эти линии.

Comment: @АндрейДобрин  Вы вот здесь покажите мне эти линии : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/EJoxvo

Comment: На самом деле их тут не видно, но если поменять цвет у блока `box`, на белый, то они будут видны. Это странная штука, и наверно, я ее оставлю. Просто затемню фон у блока `box` и все. Просто, это бы мне понадобилось в будущем при загрузке страницы.